# Accidentally deleted docker networks, now containers won't start

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I had a persistent state in a MySQL container I wanted to get rid of. Being a noob, I found a command which should do this for me - `docker-compose down -v`

I figured that if I change the YAML compose file so that it contains only the container whose state I want to delete, start it and then disable it using the command above, it will not touch other containers in any way. So that's what I did, I started only the one container, ran the command and after restarting it, the state was indeed gone. So far so good.

However, when I try to start the original bunch of containers, this is what happens:

```
ERROR: for mongo  Cannot start service mongo: network 9d1660acaba98e16fb130dd38b48a3ef0dedfd7a291b4ad6f7c7f280d72a86a4 not found
```

I do not understand what happened there. What is the right way to fix it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I was able to fix it using the following command. I have no idea whether it was the right thing to do, so be careful when applying it.

```
docker network create 9d1660acaba98e16fb130dd38b48a3ef0dedfd7a291b4ad6f7c7f280d72a86a4
```

Edit: It worked only once. Now I get the following error:

```
endpoint with name [name] already exists in network 9d1660acaba98e16fb130dd38b48a3ef0dedfd7a291b4ad6f7c7f280d72a86a4
```

Edit 2: The reason it worked only once was that I forgot to stop the network before trying to start it again.

Comment: And how did you come up with this long id?

Comment: @Soren I took it from the error I got, see the question.

Answer (score 5):

As you have deleted your networks, you would need to delete the containers as well and re-start docker again.

Just doing `docker container prune` should fix it.

Comment: Nope did not work.

Answer (score -1):

I was also able to fix it by using same command. it is working because when a container start, it's search for network associated with it and when it does not find, it refuses to start and when we create network with same network id, it create network with deleted network id as a name and when we start MySQL container, it start successfully because it got the network with same network id which was deleted.
So by follow this process you need not delete your MySQL container and your database is safe but it will only work until that fake network is avialable which had been created with deleted network id as name of network. it will not work if you delete that network.
I have tried disconnecting deleted network id with MySQL container and deleted fake network but it did not worked. After that I had to create another fake network with same network id of first fake network id.

docker network create 9d1660acaba98e16fb130dd38b48a3ef0dedfd7a291b4ad6f7c7f280d72a86a4

Comment: You need to write well to read.

It is better to express it in the form of a line break or code format if necessary.
Please refer to the following link.
https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help